# Canvas Arc Issue - Arc Animation wiping out the Canvas default values

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

Canvas Arc Issue - Animation wiping out the Canvas default values - Chartjs new Gauge type.
I worked on overriding chart js Gauge by animating new the current value:

Initial view:
[image]

The issue with the view:

1. The arc is wiping out previously drawn gauge since I am replacing with white circles

[image]

Expected view:

- Animates to the intended position without wiping out the previous canvas.
- While animating the old bar color changes until the intended progress point.

The issue is with:

- Wiping out canvas issue is with : GaugeChartHelper.prototype.clearValueCircle
- Animation: I was not able to figure out a nice way to change gauge progress color

Note: I am very new to canvas drawing. So providing examples or any help is appreciated.

fiddle:
[JSFIDDLE Link](https://jsfiddle.net/snehav27/48cbg2s7/14/)

```js
  var settings = {
    type: "tsgauge",
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: ["#ccc", "#ccc", "#ccc"],
        borderWidth: 0,
        gaugeData: {
          value: 500,
          valueColor: "#ff7143"
        },
        gaugeLimits: [0, 100, 250, 550],
        gaugeEarned: [0, 1200, 3000, 5000],
        gaugeCurrency: "mi",

      }]
    },
    options: {
      events: [],
      showMarkers: true
    }
  };
  function initChart() {
     var $indicatorElement = document.getElementById("mn_canvas");
  var indicatorElementContext = $indicatorElement.getContext("2d");
    new Chart(indicatorElementContext, settings);
  };

  function GaugeChartHelper() {}
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.setup = function(chart, config) {
    this.chart = chart;
    this.ctx = chart.ctx;
    this.limits = config.data.datasets[0].gaugeLimits;
    this.earning = config.data.datasets[0].gaugeEarned;
    this.language = config.data.datasets[0].gaugeCurrency;
    this.data = config.data.datasets[0].gaugeData;
    var options = chart.options;
    this.fontSize = options.defaultFontSize;
    this.fontStyle = options.defaultFontFamily;
    this.fontColor = options.defaultFontColor;
    this.ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
    this.circleAngle = 25 * Math.PI / 180;
    this.circleColor = config.options.indicatorColor || options.circleColor;
    this.showMarkers = typeof(config.options.showMarkers) === 'undefined' ? true : config.options.showMarkers;
    if (config.options.markerFormatFn) {
      this.markerFormatFn = config.options.markerFormatFn;
    } else {
      this.markerFormatFn = function(value) {
        return value;
      }
    }
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.applyGaugeConfig = function(chartConfig) {
    this.calcLimits();
    chartConfig.data.datasets[0].data = this.doughnutData;
    var ctx = this.ctx;
    var labelsWidth = this.limits.map(function(label) {
      var text = this.markerFormatFn(label);
      return ctx.measureText(text).width;
    }.bind(this));
    var padding = Math.max.apply(this, labelsWidth) + this.chart.width / 35 + 10;
    var heightRatio = this.chart.height / 50;
    chartConfig.options.layout.padding = {
      top: this.fontSize + heightRatio + 10,
      left: padding + 10,
      right: padding + 10,
      bottom: heightRatio * 2
    };
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.calcLimits = function() {
    var limits = this.limits;
    var data = [];
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1, ln = limits.length; i < ln; i++) {
      var dataValue = Math.abs(limits[i] - limits[i - 1]);
      total += dataValue;
      data.push(dataValue);
    }
    this.doughnutData = data;
    var minValue = limits[0];
    var maxValue = limits[limits.length - 1];
    this.isRevers = minValue > maxValue;
    this.minValue = this.isRevers ? maxValue : minValue;
    this.totalValue = total;
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.updateGaugeDimensions = function() {
    var chartArea = this.chart.chartArea;
    this.gaugeRadius = this.chart.innerRadius;
    this.gaugeCenterX = (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2;
    this.gaugeCenterY = (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom + this.chart.outerRadius) / 2;
    this.circleLength = this.chart.radiusLength * .8;
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.getCoordOnCircle = function(r, alpha) {
    return {
      x: r * Math.cos(alpha),
      y: r * Math.sin(alpha)
    };
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.getAngleOfValue = function(value) {
    var result = 0;
    var gaugeValue = value - this.minValue;
    if (gaugeValue <= 0) {
      result = 0;
    } else if (gaugeValue >= this.totalValue) {
      result = Math.PI;
    } else {
      result = Math.PI * gaugeValue / this.totalValue;
    }
    if (this.isRevers) {
      return Math.PI - result;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.renderLimitLabel = function(value, earningValue) {
    var ctx = this.ctx;
    var angle = this.getAngleOfValue(value);
    var coord = this.getCoordOnCircle(this.chart.outerRadius + (this.chart.radiusLength / 2), angle);
    var align;
    var diff = angle - (Math.PI / 2);
    if (diff > 0) {
      align = "left";
    } else if (diff < 0) {
      align = "right";
    } else {
      align = "center";
    }
    /* ctx.textAlign = align;
     ctx.font = this.fontSize + "px " + this.fontStyle;
     ctx.fillStyle = this.fontColor;
     var text = '$' + this.markerFormatFn(value);
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = "#ccc";
     ctx.arc(this.gaugeCenterX - coord.x, this.gaugeCenterY - coord.y, this.circleLength, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
     ctx.fill();

     ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
     ctx.textAlign = 'center';
     ctx.fillText(text, this.gaugeCenterX - coord.x, this.gaugeCenterY - coord.y);*/

    if (value !== 0) {
      this.renderCircle(this.gaugeRadius, angle, this.circleLength, this.circleAngle, '#ccc', value);
    }

    ctx.textAlign = align;
    ctx.font = this.fontSize + "px " + this.fontStyle;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
    ctx.fillText(earningValue + " mi", this.gaugeCenterX - coord.x, this.gaugeCenterY - coord.y);
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.renderCircle = function(radius, angle, circleLength, circleAngle, circleColor, value) {
    var text = "$" + (typeof value === "number" ? value : this.data.value);
    var coord = this.getCoordOnCircle(radius * 1.18, angle);
    var circlePoint = {
      x: this.gaugeCenterX - coord.x,
      y: this.gaugeCenterY - coord.y
    };
    var ctx = this.ctx;
    ctx.fillStyle = circleColor;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(circlePoint.x, circlePoint.y);
    coord = this.getCoordOnCircle(circleLength * 1.18, angle - circleAngle);
    ctx.arc((circlePoint.x + coord.x), (circlePoint.y + coord.y), circleLength, 0, 25 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = "8px " + this.fontStyle;
    ctx.fillText(text, (circlePoint.x + coord.x), (circlePoint.y + coord.y) + 3);
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.renderLimits = function() {
    for (var i = 0, ln = this.limits.length; i < ln; i++) {
      this.renderLimitLabel(this.limits[i], this.earning[i]);
    }
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.renderValueLabel = function() {
    var label = this.data.value.toString();
    var ctx = this.ctx;
    ctx.font = "30px " + this.fontStyle;
    var stringWidth = ctx.measureText(label).width;
    var elementWidth = 0.75 * this.gaugeRadius * 2;
    var widthRatio = elementWidth / stringWidth;
    var newFontSize = Math.floor(30 * widthRatio);
    var fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, this.gaugeRadius);
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.font = "30px " + this.fontStyle;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.data.valueColor || this.fontColor;
    ctx.fillText(label, this.gaugeCenterX, this.gaugeCenterY);
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.renderValueCircle = function(value) {
    var angle = this.getAngleOfValue(typeof value === "number" ? value : this.data.value);
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    this.renderCircle(this.gaugeRadius, angle, this.circleLength, this.circleAngle, this.circleColor, value);
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.renderSmallValueCircle = function(value) {
    var angle = this.getAngleOfValue(value);
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    this.renderCircle(this.gaugeRadius - 1, angle, this.circleLength - 1, this.circleAngle, this.circleColor, value);
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.clearValueCircle = function(value) {
    var angle = this.getAngleOfValue(value);
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 0;
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    this.renderCircle(this.gaugeRadius - 1, angle, this.circleLength + 1, this.circleAngle, "#fff", value);
    this.ctx.stroke();
  };
  GaugeChartHelper.prototype.animateCircle = function() {
    var stepCount = 30;
    var animateTimeout = 300;
    var gaugeValue = this.data.value - this.minValue;
    var step = gaugeValue / stepCount;
    var i = 0;
    var currentValue = this.minValue;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      i++;
      this.clearValueCircle(currentValue);
      if (i > stepCount) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        this.renderValueCircle();
      } else {
        currentValue += step;
        this.renderSmallValueCircle(currentValue);
      }
    }.bind(this), animateTimeout / stepCount);
  };
  Chart.defaults.tsgauge = {
    animation: {
      animateRotate: false,
      animateScale: false
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 88,
    rotation: Math.PI,
    circumference: Math.PI,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {},
    circleColor: "#444"
  };
  Chart.controllers.tsgauge = Chart.controllers.doughnut.extend({
    initialize: function(chart) {
      var gaugeHelper = this.gaugeHelper = new GaugeChartHelper();
      gaugeHelper.setup(chart, chart.config);
      gaugeHelper.applyGaugeConfig(chart.config);
      chart.config.options.animation.onComplete = function(chartElement) {
        gaugeHelper.updateGaugeDimensions();
        gaugeHelper.animateCircle();
      };
      Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    draw: function() {
      Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
      var gaugeHelper = this.gaugeHelper;
      gaugeHelper.updateGaugeDimensions();
      gaugeHelper.renderValueLabel();
      if (gaugeHelper.showMarkers) {
        gaugeHelper.renderLimits();
      }
      gaugeHelper.renderSmallValueCircle(gaugeHelper.minValue);
    }
  });
  
  initChart();
```

```css
.mn_indicatorCanvasContainer {
  width:  400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="mn_indicatorCanvasContainer">
  <canvas id="mn_canvas" class="mn_canvas">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Any control over "z index"?

Comment: @GetSet I dont think I can set z-index since I am replacing the blackcircle with white circle I might need to find a different way.

Comment: You said it `I am replacing with white circles` don't do that just redraw entire canvas on each frame

Comment: Use a second canvas (BG) to render permanent parts of gauge. Every update clear display canvas, draw BG canvas onto display canvas, then render changeable content.

Comment: @Blindman67 yes I am trying that after checking other post.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I am afraid If I will be able to redraw the canvas since its an extention of ChartJS or if you have example it would be helpful for me to understand  how redraw works and how I can fit that into the context